# Grails: Set of Integer not persisting when I create a domain object and save it

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my grails application I am constructing a domain object. I add elements to a Set property of the domain class. I then save the domain object with `.save(flush: true)`. Then I print out the size of the set to the command line and get `2` as expected. However, when I retrieve that same object right after in what is essentially my RESTFUL GET method and print out the size of the set I get `0` as if I had never added the elements and saved the changes. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: There is something going wrong with your RESTFUL service.

Comment: showing some code would be helpful